# Trouble Comparing Items in List

Tags: python

I have some code that inputs the current market price into a list, and then compares the last two values in that list (in theory). When the market goes up, it prints to the terminal `market is up`, when down, `market is down`. However, my code is always printing `market is down` (I have checked and the market is indeed up between scrapes). What am I doing wrong? I have a sneaking suspicion I don't understand list indexing.

Code:

````
    tickers = ['^N225']
    for ticker in tickers:
            ticker_yahoo = yf.Ticker(ticker)
            data = ticker_yahoo.history()
            last_quote = data['Close'].iloc[-1]
            L = float(last_quote)
            M = trunc(L)
            f = open('market.txt', 'a')
            f.write(str(L))
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(str(L))
            print(M)
            list = []
            list.append(M)
            N = list[-1]
            O = list[0]
            if N > O:
                print("Market is up")
            else:
                print("Market is down")

            time.sleep(10)```
````

Comment: (1) Never use `list` as a variable name; it is (at the very least) confusing to name something like a built-in. (2) The last two elements are `[-2]` and `[-1]`; `[0]` is the first element.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm missing something,

It looks like you are appending a float (M) to an empty list (list)
so list[0] and list[-1] are both M.

If M is a list (?)

using "append" insert a single element so you generate a list of list with a single list element

```py
list = []
other = [1,2,3,4]
list.append(other) # [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

print(list[0]) # [1,2,3,4]
print(list[-1]) # [1,2,3,4]

# you should prefer
list = []
other = [1,2,3,4]
list.extend(other)

print(list[0]) # 1
print(list[-1]) # 4
# expected ?
print(list[-2]) # 3
```

simply why not making comparison on M items (if M is a list)